# Firefox Extensions: adding functionality to existing Chrome XUL elements

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, dom-events, xul

For kicks and giggles, I'm trying to write a Firefox extension.  Just a really simple one. I've gone through the tutorials I've found, and I've gotten the basic "Hello, World" app working.

What I'd like to do, is add an event listener to an existing element in the <del>browser's</del> Firefox Application DOM (i.e. tabs).  So far, all the resources I've been able to find show how to add a new element to the application and then add an action to it using Javascript.  I've tried several ways of going about adding a Javascript function (which I know works, as I've successfully added elements with the function) to existing elements.

My latest attempt at this is structured as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- in myExtension.xul -->

<overlay  id="myExtension"
          xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul">
  <script type="application/x-javascript">
    var tabs = document.getElementsByTagName("tabbrowser-tab")
    var len = tabs.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
      tabs[i].ondblclick = function() {
        alert('bam!');
      }
    };
  </script>

</overlay>
```

None of this stuff works.  Like I said, I'm totally new to this stuff, and I just got a little inspired for a weekend project.  Maybe there's some way of making sure I'm accessing the chrome document rather than the page document? <del>Although when I try to get page elements (i.e. "p") using this technique, that doesn't work either, so that's probably a dead end.</del>

[edit]
To attempt to clear up some confusion:

What I mean by "the *browser's* DOM" is elements that are part of the chrome interface, *not* webpage elements. I'm talking about putting an event listener specifically on an element that already exists as part of the Firefox application UI, such as a tab (not the content of the tab, but the tab itself), or say, the Home button. I want to redefine behavior of parts of the Firefox Application GUI.

Say, for instance, that I wanted to add an alert every time someone clicked the "New Tab" button, or the "Close Tab" button.  Or if I wanted to redefine the "Reload" button to redirect to the root of the domain of the current tab rather than just reloading the page.  These are all existing parts of Firefox, and I want to redefine them/overwrite them through an extension, specifically by adding a javascript action to them.

[/edit]

[sidenote]Is embedded javascript allowed in an xul?  Or does it need to be in a separate file?[/sidenote]

Anyone have any advice on this?

Comment: Doesn't document.getElementsByTagName("tabbrowser-tab") return a NodeList? Have you tried to get the first tab and register a listener to it? 

Could you post your extension somewhere?

Comment: I actually noticed that problem a while ago, and have since modified my code attempt.  Updated to latest attempt.

Comment: The project is here: https://github.com/shekibobo/PinFresh

Answer (score 4):

The javascript code in the overlay code doesn't work because it runs earlier than gbrowser contains any tabs.

In Firefox (or Thunderbird) extensions you usually start your extension in a load event listener:

```
window.addEventListener("load",
                         pinfresh.init,
                         false);
```

The init function then needs to register event listeners for various tab events:

```
  pub.init = function() {
    var container = gBrowser.tabContainer;

    container.addEventListener("TabOpen", tabOpened, false);
    container.addEventListener("TabClose", tabRemoved, false);
  };
```

When a new tab is opened we register another listener which will trigger the tab reload when the user double clicks on the tab:

```
  tabOpened = function(e) {
    var tab = e.target;
    tab.addEventListener("dblclick", tabDoubleClicked, false);
  }

  tabDoubleClicked = function(e) {
    gBrowser.reloadTab(e.target);
  }
```

The complete code looks like this:

```
<overlay  id="pinfresh"
          xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul">
  <script type="application/x-javascript">
    pinfresh = function() {
      var pub = {};

      tabOpened = function(e) {
        var tab = e.target;
        tab.addEventListener("dblclick", tabDoubleClicked, false);
      }

      tabRemoved = function(e) {
        var tab = e.target;

        tab.removeEventListener("dblclick", tabDoubleClicked, false);
      }

      tabDoubleClicked = function(e) {
        gBrowser.reloadTab(e.target);
      }

      pub.init = function() {
        var container = gBrowser.tabContainer;

        container.addEventListener("TabOpen", tabOpened, false);
        container.addEventListener("TabClose", tabRemoved, false);
      };

      return pub;
    }();

    window.addEventListener("load",
                            pinfresh.init,
                            false);

  </script>
</overlay>
```

For code snippets to work with tabs I recommend the [Tab Browser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Code_snippets/Tabbed_browser) page at the Mozilla Development Center.

I recommend putting the Javascript code in its own file instead of including it in the XUL file. Errors in external Javascript files show up in Firefox's error console which makes debugging a lot easier.

Comment: Don't want you to think I'm ignoring this answer.  I just haven't had time to try this out, and probably won't until May. It's a lot more information than I expected, and has given me a lot to study during final semester crunch time.

Comment: I can give you the modified sources if you want. How can I reach you?

Answer (score 3):

In order to get a page element of the current viewed tab you first need to get the document itself with gBrowser.selectedBrowser.contentDocument

So basically if you had a `<p id='test'>blah</p>` element and u want to manipulate it you could do `var p = gBrowser.selectedBrowser.contentDocument.getElementById('test');` and then do with it whatever you want.

Regarding "adding an event listener to an existing element in the browser's DOM (i.e. tabs)", I'm sorry but I fail to understand what you want, do you want to manipulate the browser GUI (i.e. adding a button to the navigation bar) or do you want to manipulate the DOM content of the tab (i.e. the viewed site)? (basically "browser" can mean lot's of things :)).

Comment: +1 for the browser content solution.  But basically, I want to add a dblclick action to certain browser tabs.  As my code example above shows, I don't want to add elements, I just want to make existing elements do something different than their defaults.

Comment: Much like how you can add functionality to page elements using jQuery... you don't actually have to make new elements, you just find them in the DOM and assign some functionality.  $(document).ready(function() { $("tabbrowser-tab").dblclick(alert('tab')) });

Comment: Sorry again but I still don't understand what you mean by "certain browser tabs". do you mean the browser tab itself (where currently you click on one and the browser display its content) or you mean the "content of the tab" which is the website HTML?

For example, now I see your question and comments at the content of the tab and also see that the selected tab of the browser got the icon (favicon) of Stackoverflow.

Comment: Just in case you want to add an event listener to an element at the content of the tab (i.e. displayed site for instance), read [Ajaxian Event listener](http://ajaxian.com/archives/an-alternative-way-to-addeventlistener) and use that to create an event listener of whatever type you want.

At my extension I used the code they give as a standalone js file which I call at the start of my code and then whenever I want to attach an event to an element I do:
var lst   = El.createEventListener();
img.addEventListener("click", lst, false);
lst.addEvent("click", function (e, callback, object) {code..}

Comment: edited post to attempt to clear up confusion. I guess the word "browser" has been confusing.  I'm talking about changing behavior of Firefox Application DOM elements. This has more to do with the XUL elements that make up Firefox than elements of the HTML DOM.

Comment: This is doable. As I wrote in my comment above, could you upload your extension somewhere? This way it's easier to find out why it's not working for you.